# How to implement crypto refunds in a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, payable, payments, smart-contract-wallets

I am quite new to cryptocurrencies and after some investigation I thought this might be the right place to ask.

**Problem**: I have a small business and I would like to offer to my customers the option to pay with some cryptocurrencies (ex: Bitcoin). However I would like to receive the money only if my job has been performed on time. Otherwise they get a discount of x%. I believe this can be done with smart contracts and as far as I understand the Ethereum platform offers the option to do so by deploying a code that does so.

[image]

I tried to code myself the logic by following some youtube tutorials and even though they mention the possibility to achieve what I want to do, the examples are always oversimplified and do not implement the "IF THIS THAN THAT" condition which is fundamental for my business.

**Question**: Do you know if there is a minimal valuable example that accomplishes this task? Or can you point me to some resources where I can find some help please?

Comment: You can't monitor/accept Bitcoin with Ethereum - unless it's a wrapped Bitcoin (wBTC) token. So it has to be an asset which exists in the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Does this mean that I cannot put as part of the smart contract a value in BTC and an address which points to the Bitcoin blockchain so that the payment is applied only if a certain condition is met?

Comment: No you can't. A blockchain is a deterministic system, so it can only use data inside it, it can't directly interact with data outside the blockchain. There are indirect ways to get external data in the blockchain, but then some entity needs to feed the data there.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand because from the tutorials I followed, a smart contract is code (which is unchangeable) wrote in solidity and it can interact for example to a simple html page which can read and write some of the variables of the code (but not change it). Therefore I would expect it can trigger a function that sends the crypto to an address. Do you have any hint about how I could achive this task please?

Comment: No, your smart contract cannot directly send bitcoins (except wBTC as stated earlier). The smart contract can trigger an event that a centralized system can listen on and automatically send bitcoins accordingly.